# URL links not appearing correctly with BibTex

Tags: bibtex

I am getting problems with the URL links in the bibliography. The URL links are appearing haphazardly in my bibliography, with one of the URLs going out of the page itself. I am attaching a pic for reference

[image]

The packages I am using are

```
    \usepackage[comma]{natbib} 
    \usepackage{har2nat} 
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{underscore}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

THe biliography style I am using is `agsm`. The code is the following

```
    \bibliographystyle{agsm} 

    \nocite{*}

    \bibliography{Bibliography}
```

I request urgent help with the alignment of the URLs as I have to submit a first draft of my thesis on Monday.

Comment: Have you tried loading the `url` package with the options `hyphens` and `spaces`?

Comment: Hi Mico. I dd try \usepackage[hyphens]{url} but I am getting an 'options clash for url' error

Comment: If this is still interesting: try change order of packages loaded? It seems like `url` is already loaded by another package prior to your `\usepackage{url}`.

Comment: try to use of breakurl.sty

Comment: @venkatesanRamachandiran: I did. It is not working.

Comment: @Mats: Where do you suggest I put the url package?

Comment: @Karthik, I'd just put it first and hope for the best. Without reading the (sparse) package documentations for the packages `natbib` and `har2nat`, the "'options clash for url' error" suggests that one of those packages loads `url` without the `hyphen` option. Let me know how if it works out for you.

Comment: ...although, inspecting style files for the packages, I cannot find any loading of the `url` package. If this is still an urgent issue, please post code so that people that want to help can reproduce the error or the erroneous output. It is common to do so by means of an MWE, instead of the entire text (in your case, your thesis). You can do so by "editing" the text of the question. Perhaps this can be solved before you _final_ version of the thesis is due :)